# Do Achatinas appreciate communication with human?

Tags: behavior, aquarium, snails

Do Achatinas appreciate communication with human, or is it just a stress to them?

When you take them in your arms, they seem to move more actively then in the terrarium, but do they appreciate that, is it good for their health?

As they are cold blooded, they should like a source of warmth such as human hand in theory. I know of a pet lizard which likes to stay on one's knees, as it is seemingly warm for him and he needs to warm up his body as it's cold blooded, ignoring communication at the same time. Is it the same with snails?